# How to remove spaces before and after the comma in java

Tags: java, if-statement, io

I have an input mismatch error.

used regular expression ("//s*,//s*",",") but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you mean `\\s` instead of `//s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `\\` instead of `//`

```
String input = "a , b , c , d";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*", ",");
System.out.println(output); // output: "a,b,c,d"
```